# Getting Flash UI components into Builder

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I've recently been working on an app in Flash and have decided to move to Flash Builder 4 for the improved debugging and editing.

Problem is when I get to run the application, I get the error:

```
    1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: 
SliderEvent.    SpiroUI.as  /SpiroPaint/src/circles line 114    Flex Problem
```

The offending function is:

```
    public function circOuterRotation(e:SliderEvent):void 
    {
        spiroInstance.setCircOuterRotation(e.target.value);
    }
```

Not sure how I can get the SliderEvent to be recognised as it is. It all worked perfectly in Flash.

I have include `import fl.events.SliderEvent` for the class, that didn't work.

At the moment this is the only error I'm getting, and the app window opens but nothing appears in it.

Is there some MXML code I need to import the slider? As in the equivalent to importing into the Flash project Library?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually add the "fl" components to your Flash Builder source path.

1. Right-click on your project in Flash Builder, and go to Properties.
2. Select "ActionScript Build Path" from the left.
3. Go to the "Source path" tab now available on the right.
4. Click "Add Folder..."
5. The Flash components should be in a location with a path similar to the following, depending on what version of the Flash IDE you have and where you installed it.

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface